# How to use freeslick with oracle with play-framework scala?

Tags: oracle, scala, playframework, slick

I am looking for an example play framework project that shows how to access an oracle database through freeslick in a scala play framework application.

Any hints?

Comment: Did my answer help? How can I improve it?

Answer (score 2):

[Check out the Play! docs.](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.0-RC1/ScalaSlickDrivers)

[You can specify the JDBC driver.](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.0-RC1/ScalaSlickDrivers#Non-free-JDBC-drivers)

[You can add the JDBC Oracle driver using unmanaged jars.](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/SBTDependencies#Unmanaged-dependencies)